# Unable to boot after restoring disc image

Tags: boot, gnome, restore, disk-image

I bought a new SSD and wanted to restore my previous Ubuntu install. I used gnome's disk utility tool to create the image on an external hard drive.

Once I was done installing Ubuntu through a live USB, I went back to gnome's disk utility and restored the disk image.

As soon as I restart, I get the error that says: `No bootable device found`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Secure Boot" in the BIOS settings, and check that "Legacy Boot" is enabled.

I ran into this same problem while similarily trying to boot a recently-restored (to a different SSD) disk image. In my case, disabling secure boot was all it took to get the image to boot.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the times, the problem is that the connection to the SSD isn't well connected and disconnects frequently. You also have to check if you connected it to the right port. It can also be that Secure boot is enabled. Secure boot is made to not pick up any devices found in ports with the intention of protecting the user from malware, but it can also not pick up any devices without malware. Also, make sure you pick the right device.